# How can I include an arbitrary file into a HAML template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to have independent .markdown files that I then include in my haml templates. So I want to somehow include -- not render -- an external file into the template. I want the parent file to have `:markdown` in it, with the inclusion directly below that, and then the .markdown file to just be pure markdown.

Or: Is there a way to just use markdown as a rails template language (same way i can write templates or partials in erb or haml and rails just figures it out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I could think of is to [create a custom template handler](http://www.slideshare.net/digx/hardcore-extending-rails-3-from-railsconf-10) for Markdown. That you get to use Markdown code as partials (also getting support for locals for free).

```
module Markdown
  class Template < ActionView::Template::Handler
    include ActionView::Template::Handlers::Compilable

    self.default_format = Mime::HTML

    def compile(template)
      '"' + Maruku.new(template.source).to_html + '".html_safe'
    end
  end
end
```

And then register it with markdown extension (in application.rb or custom initializer):

```
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler(:md, Markdown::Template)
```

And then user render like you would for any partial :)

```
# for file foo.md
= render 'foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to your solution, but using the `:markdown` filter. Haml does string interpolation on any filtered text, so you can read the markdown file like this.

```
:markdown
  #{File.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "foo.markdown"))}
```

You could put this into a helper, but you'd have to be careful with the file paths.

Comment: Ohhh nice, much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I can come up with (no haml filter involved at all):

```
=raw Maruku.new(File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/foo.markdown')).to_html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I asked the HAML developers a while back. I suggested we needed an `:include` filter for HAML. Their response was we should load the file into a variable and then use the variable like we would any other.

Answer (score 0):

Extending `ActionView::Template::Handler` is deprecated in at least Rails 3.1.0.  Instead the following worked for me:

In `lib/markdown_views.rb`:

```
require "rdiscount"

class MarkdownViews

  def call template
    'md = ERB.new(<<\'EOF\'%s
EOF
).result( binding)
    RDiscount.new( md).to_html.html_safe'% template.source
  end

end
```

In `config/application.rb`:

```
require "markdown_views"
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :markdown, MarkdownViews.new
```

In `views/public/home.html.markdown`:

```
# H1

  + Bullets.
  + screaming.
  + from out of nowhere

<%= "Embedded Ruby" %>
```